# Реализация передаваемых пакетов

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос заключается в следующем:
Есть java сервер и Android клиент.
Копал в Интернете клиент-серверные подключения, передача определенных данных и прочее, но так и не понял, как передавать определенные пакеты по определенному действию.

Пример:

Запущен сервер, ожидающий подключений.
Заходим в андроид приложение, в котором 3 TextView, куда мы ввели 3 различных текстовых значения и кнопка ОК. Нажимаем на кнопку ок - создается Socket подключение к серверу, и, допустим, отправляется на сервер пакет в виде байтов и опкода, в котором содержится эти 3 введенных значения, сервер принимает этот пакет и "раскладывает", помещая эти 3 разных значения в разные переменные.

Для меня очень важно, чтобы это была пакетная обработка, т.е. если я добавлю, допустим, еще 1 кнопку ОК(2), то по её нажатию клиент посылает серверу так же 3 значения, но сервер уже будет обрабатывать их по-другому.

--->Т.е. берем пакет клиента с опкодом 0x01 и отсылаем серверу. По этому опкоду сервер делает определенные действия. Берем пакет клиента с опкодом 0x02 - отправляем серверу и по этому опкоду сервер уже делает другие действия... Принцип данного вопроса, думаю, я объяснил правильно. 
Желательно покидать примеры кода.

Comment: Post/Get запросы вам чем не понравились?

Comment: @VladEv1L, а вы уверены, что вам нужны именно сокеты? Обычно такие задачи решаются при помощи RESTfull сервиса, и, как пишет @nekaneka, Post/Get и др. запросов.

Comment: @VladEv1L, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Есть удобный и наглядный способ решить вашу задачу.
Андроид клиент создает AsyncTask и в его потоке отправляет запросы на сервер. Урок по AsyncTask можно найти [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer). А внутри метода doInBackground формируте [GET или POST](http://littlebrains.ru/history/33) запрос.

Comment: Не знаю, но гэт и пост запросы для меня звучат как в php передача данных на сайт, но это лишь передача обычных данных, в будущем в моем проекте то будет ежесекундная передача пакета об обновлении допустим персонажа, координат, разные проверки и будет множество пакетов. Я спрашиваю про пакеты потому как лично видел код игрового сервера. Принцип то понятен, в голове уложить можно, но настроить это сложнее все. 
Ведь сами посудите - легче взять и отправить от клиента пакет с опкодом, сервер же его пример и будет знать что делать с ним. Пост и гет запросы - это если создавать чат какой-либо)

Comment: Или давайте проще - просто нужно распределить в клиенте байты так: 
Отправляем серверу байты:
0x01
account_name

Сервер видит 0x01 и передает его содержимое на переработку. 
В обработке он посылает назад пакет с опкодом и содержимым. Клиент передает его на обработку.

Comment: Так чем вам Пост и гет запросы не понравились. Это самое простое, в тело запроса можно писать что угодно и на сервере обрабатывать. Плюс написано уже до вас - не надо городить велосипеды.

Comment: Понимаете, я могу переслать эти 2 строчки серверу спокойно:
 
    String login = GetRegLogin.getText().toString();

    String password = GetRegpassword.getText().toString();

    out.writeUTF(login);

    out.writeUTF(password);

Так же как и сервер их принимает нормально:

    String login = null;

          String password = null;

          while(true) {

            login = in.readUTF();

            password = in.readUTF();

            System.out.println("Логин клиента: " + login + " Пароль клиента: " + password);

Но это не то, как и гет, и пост запросы...

Comment: Хорошо, в чем именно проблема. Почему это не то?

Comment: Составил небольшую схему вместо объяснений:
http://savepic.su/4915908.png

Comment: @VladEv1L, обычно в подобных протоколах обмена между клиентом и сервером по TCP в начало "пакета" кладут его размер (например, в байтах).

Обычно этого достаточно для бесконфликтной обработки.